# Yii CActiveRecord "search on" and search()

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on a project that uses the Yii framework and CActiveRecord models.

In all of them there is something like this:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        //...
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array(
            'id, alias, code',
            'safe', 'on'=>'search'
        ),
    );
}
```

and a method called `search()`.

The question - what is this for, and can I safely remove it if I don't use any of the Zii / Gii / whatever stuff? I also don't use forms and mass assignment.

I suspect this was auto-generated by Gii for whatever reason. I tried commenting it out and didn't notice any problems, but maybe I've broken something.

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't use forms and mass assignment.

Then yes you won't need it (but in any other case you will, so imo you might as well leave it there). Here is an article explaining it really well:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/